# Twin Arrays - Compile Time error in C

Tags: c, algorithm, compiler-errors

**Problem**
You are given two arrays and each containing integers. You need to choose exactly number from A and exactly number from B such that the index of the two chosen numbers is not same and the sum of the 2 chosen values is minimum.

Your objective is to find and print this minimum value.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer denoting the size of two arrays.
Each of the next two lines contains space separated integers denoting array and respectively.

Constraints

Output Format

Print the minimum sum which can be obtained under the conditions mentioned in the problem statement.

Sample Input:

5
5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5

Sample Output:

2

Explanation:

Minimum sum will be obtained by chosing number at the last index of first array and first index of the second array, i.e. . 2

**Solution**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int lower(int *g,int index,int n){
    int r,low,i;
    if(index!=0){
        low = g[0];
    }
    else
    {
        low = g[1];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i!=-1&&g[i]<low){
            low=g[i];
            r=i;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
int main(){
    int n,al1,al2,bl1,bl2,index,sum=0,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int *a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int *b = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for ( i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    al1 = lower(a,-1,n);
//  al2 = lower(a,al1,n);
    bl1 = lower(b,-1,n);
    bl2 = lower(b,bl1,n);
    if(al1!=bl1){
        sum=a[al1]+b[bl1];
    }
    else{
        sum = a[al1]+b[bl2];
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Note : I compiled it in Dev C++ Compiler and I got output but when I run it in online compiler, I get **Compile time error**

Comment: Is there an error message? It would help if you posted it. What online compiler are you using?

Comment: Could there have been a copy/paste error when you pasted the code into the online compiler?

Comment: @DavidBowling - There is no copy paster error.

Comment: You should fix code to remove warnings, and try again. There are two unused variables.

Comment: It gives runtime error when I ran it on an online [compiler](https://www.codechef.com/ide) with the input you gave.

Comment: Error:   GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 26079]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  main () at solution.c:36
36   sum=a[al1]+b[bl1];
#0  main () at solution.c:36'

Comment: You need to learn how to turn up the warning level on your off-line compiler. You should be getting warnings, and you need to fix every single one of those warnings.

Comment: `if(i!=-1&&g[i]<low){}`-- why compare `i` with `-1`? `i` can never be `-1` in this loop, so the first condition is always true. Also,  consider adding some whitespace to improve legibility.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you would have linked the online compiler you mentioned, such that someone could have tried to reproduce the issue. However, just looking at the code, there are some obvious compile-related problems.

Be careful what C standard you use. C89 standards don't allow for in-line comments.

```
// comments like these should be replaced with 
/* comments like these 
 */
```

Another good practice when compiling is to use `-Wall` and `-Werror`. These flags turn on notifications for all warnings(`-Wall`) and treats them all as errors(`-Werror`). It can be annoying at first, as it forces you to cast everything and remove all unused variables, but in time it pays off. As mentioned by [David Bowling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6879826/david-bowling), you have 2 unused variables.

You are also a risk of runtime errors when working with malloc and pointers in general. Since it is somewhat outside the scope of the question, I will only point out the obvious: `low = g[1];` will issue a SEGFAULT if your input has n = 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are some logic problems with your algorithm which may be are leading to the SegFault and your problems.

First, you must correct in the function `lower` the code, so `r` must always have some value and not rubbish. Something like this

```
int r,low,i;

if(index==-1)
    low=g[0];

if(index==0)
    low=g[1];

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(i!=index && g[i]<=low){
        low=g[i];
        r=i;
    }
}
return r;
```

The comparison in the if statement changed to `g[i]<=low` so `r` can take the corresponding index. Also notice that we exclude the `index` from the comparisons to find the next lower one.

Second as the problem says, it must calculate the minimum sum from the two arrays but from different indexes.

So i think in your main program the code must take consideration which one of the first lower values found is the smaller to keep it and find the second smallest value from the other array.

Something like that

```
al1 = lower(a,-1,n);
bl1 = lower(b,-1,n);
if(al1!=bl1){
    sum=a[al1]+b[bl1];
}
else{
    if(a[al1]<b[bl1]) {
        bl2 = lower(b,bl1,n);
        sum = a[al1]+b[bl2];
    }
    else {
        al2 = lower(a,al1,n);
        sum = a[al2]+b[bl1];
    }
}
```

Finally you must make some check about the boundaries of the arrays because you hardcoded some indexes e.g. `g[1]`, so it must exist.